# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT' using IN clause

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I am having trouble with my query, i am trying to do a pivot table using data from SQL and I want to sum up figures from a table for all years past from 2000.

This is my query

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         Vendor_code, Vendor_name, Ord_date, SubTot, 
         DateRecieved, CurrencyCode, YearReceived
     FROM 
         [BL_CUSTOM PO HISTORY SUMMARY]) AS S
PIVOT
    (SUM(S.SubTot) 
     FOR s.YearRecived IN (SELECT STUFF((SELECT ', ' + cast(year as VARCHAR(10)) FROM [BL_CUSTOM YEAR COUNT] FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')) ) as pvt
```

I am getting the following error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 33
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 33
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: That won't work. You would need to construct the query using dynamic SQL.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: why are you stuffing the years? IN reads only the matching rows and one entity...

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the syntax in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017 
I believe your query,
SELECT STUFF((SELECT ', ' + cast(year as VARCHAR(10)) FROM [BL_CUSTOM YEAR COUNT] FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,''))
is causing the problem.